# windows credentials isn't showing github

Tags: git, github, credentials

I need to change my password by token in GitHub, but I can't because there's no way to remove the old credentials.

I'm going to Windows credentials, and there is absolutely nothing related to git/github.com.

Answer (score 0):

Then double-check:

- your remote URL (it might include the old password/token directly)

```sh
cd c:\path\to\repo
git remote -v
```

- your `git config credential.helper` output:
  If it is not "`manager`" or "`manager-core`", but "`cached`", or "`store`", or... the credentials might be cached elsewhere than the Windows Credentials Manager.

In any case, don't try "reject": to properly remove an entry from your cache 'xxx' (replace xxx by the output of `git config credential.helper`), you would do:

```
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com"|git-credential-xxx erase
```

Answer (score 0):

The Git FAQ [explains how to to this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-reset-credentials):

```
$ echo url=https://account@github.com | git credential reject
```

You should replace `account` with your GitHub account.  Then, next time you try to push or pull, Git will prompt you for your credentials and you can enter your username for the username and your PAT for the password.